# Embed Plotly in html with responsive behavior: can I change legend position based on screen width?

Tags: html, django, responsive-design, plotly-python

I am using Plotly to embed a plot on an HTML page. My website is responsive, but I am not satisfied with the legend of the plot that I have embedded. Here you can see two screenshots: on the left, we see the plot on a widescreen, and on the right with a narrow one.

[image] vs
[image]

As shown in the figure, the plot looks good on the widescreen (left). However, when the screen is narrow (right), the legend takes too much space and the plot is shrunk.

Moving the legend below when the screen is small would solve the issue (as depicted with the red drawing). Is it possible to embed such a responsive behavior in Plotly when adding the legend?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: please refer to https://plotly.com/python/legend/ i think it is possible ,have you tried to use `Horizontal Legends` it is more responsive ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it might work better than what I have! But I would still be interested to know if it exists a way to change the legend position based on the screen size

Comment: I ended up creating two versions of the plot. One for mobile , one for everything else, and disabling the legend on the mobile that way. Far from a great solution but it's as good as it gets for now.